# Copy entire row from from Sheet1(source) to the next available row of Sheet2(destination)

Tags: java, selenium

How to copy the entire row from sheet 1 to another sheet(2) of the same spreadsheet on the next available empty row? for example row 1 and 2 are not empty, how can I paste the copied row from sheet 1 to row 3 of sheet 2 and the succeeding rows using Java?

Here is the code I am working on:
I have found a code that it push down the row by 1, but I need the code that will populate the next available row.

```
public class CopyFromExcel {

    public static void copyFromExcel(data) throws Exception {

        String rowNumber = data.gr.getRowNumber();
        int rowNum = Integer.parseInt(rowNumber);

        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("file path + filename.xlsx"));
        XSSFSheet sourcesheet = workbook.getSheet("sourcesheetname");
        XSSFSheet resultsheet = workbook.getSheet("destinationsheetname");
        copyRow(workbook, sourcesheet, resultsheet, rowNum, 1);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file path + filename.xlsx");
        workbook.write(fos);
        fos.close();
    }

    private static void copyRow(XSSFWorkbook workbook, XSSFSheet sourcesheet, XSSFSheet resultsheet, int sourceRowNum, int destinationRowNum) {
        XSSFRow newRow = resultsheet.getRow(destinationRowNum);
        XSSFRow sourceRow = sourcesheet.getRow(sourceRowNum);

        // If the row exist in destination, push down all rows by 1 else create a new row
        if (newRow != null) {
            resultsheet.shiftRows(destinationRowNum, resultsheet.getLastRowNum(), 1);
        }else{
            newRow = resultsheet.createRow(destinationRowNum);
        }

        // Loop through source columns to add to new row
        for (int i = 0; i < sourceRow.getLastCellNum();  i++) {

            XSSFCell oldCell = sourceRow.getCell(i);
            XSSFCell newCell = newRow.createCell(i);

            // If the old cell is null jump to next cell
            if (oldCell == null){
                newCell = null;
                continue;
            }

            // Set the cell data type
            newCell.setCellType(oldCell.getCellType());

            // Set the cell data value
            switch (oldCell.getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                    newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getStringCellValue());
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                    newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getBooleanCellValue());
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
                    newCell.setCellErrorValue(oldCell.getErrorCellValue());
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                    newCell.setCellFormula(oldCell.getCellFormula());
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getNumericCellValue());
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getRichStringCellValue());
                    break;
            }
        }   

    }
}
```

Comment: You can check how many rows are in Sheet2 and use it as index for the next free row.

Comment: hi thanks Doshi, actually sheet 2 is  blank it only contains the header, I found a code in stackoverflow that it shifts down the entire row if not null, what I need is to skip the row with value and paste the copied row from sheet 1 below

Answer (score 0):

You may use `getLastRowNum()` on Sheet and Increment the same to get the empty row.

Comment: Hi kumar, thanks for your comment.  I did use the getlastRowNum() but it is only shifting down the row but not actually skipping to the next available row

Comment: // If the row exist in destination, push down all rows by 1 else create a new row


        if (newRow != null) {
            resultsheet.shiftRows(destinationRowNum, resultsheet.getLastRowNum(), 1);
        }else{
            newRow = resultsheet.createRow(destinationRowNum);
        }